After updates no network is found anymore by wifi antenna
Well I had after half a year of not using ubuntu half a dozen updates, around 1.9 GB of updates.
I noticed afterwards I had to reinstall the drivers for my antenna, as per here: (Driver for the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano, on Kubuntu 18.04 Previous fix from June 6 didn't work for me)
Now the antenna is found again. Yet when I open it, it doesn't show any networks available. Even though there should be plenty (not only my own, but also from the neighbours/public bar etc)
On my phone, the same computer windows partition a macbook it all works and I can perfectly fine see them. Also I know for sure it worked in the past.
How can I debug, what can I do? I've uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers and rebooted as well.

$sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 05
       serial: d8:5e:d3:5b:fe:42
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-35-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:43200000-4320ffff memory:43210000-43213fff
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@1:6.2
       logical name: wlx5ca6e66e0cd9
       serial: 5c:a6:e6:6e:0c:d9
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau driverversion=6.5.0-35-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       bus info: usb@1:4.3
       logical name: enx023402016263
       serial: 02:34:02:01:62:63
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.5.0-35-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.126.254 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair


Have you tried a different program (for example, instead of network manager you try wifi-radar)?

The starting point is working out (& telling us) what Ubuntu product & release you're using. LTS releases have kernel stack choices; and an easy fix maybe switching to the older GA kernel stack for example, but we currently don't know what options are available to you.

Please see this question for what information is needed (run the wireless info script and post a link to a pastebin of the output).
